# Is it ok to have conditional statements inside render() but outside return()?

Tags: reactjs, conditional-statements, render

Is it ok to have conditional statements inside render() but outside return()?

For example:

```
render() {
//if statement

//return
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes its ok, the render function must return a `React.Node`, its up to you to decide its implementation:

```
render() {
  if (this.state.isLoading) return <Spinner/>;
  return <App/>;
}
```